# Como transformar em uma lista elementos da diagonal de uma matriz em python

Tags: python, matriz

Tenho a seguinte matriz, de exemplo:

```
matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9, 3, 8, 9],
          [4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4],
          [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6],
          [4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Gostaria de obter apenas os elementos da diagonal principal, tal como:

```
A = [1, 8, 2, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não fez sentido. Por favor, leia o guia de [ask] e reformule-a. Se é novo na comunidade, recomendo fazer o [tour] também.

Comment: Coloque um exemplo do que quer para deixar mais claro, assim não da para entender

Comment: Tentei deixar mais claro o exemplo

Comment: E como sua matriz está definida no Python? Coloque isso na pergunta também.

Comment: Mas esta na pergunta

Comment: @AlexandreCandidoTeixeira Não está. Na pergunta há uma representação da matriz, mas não está como você está definindo-a no Python. Isso pode mudar completamente a resposta e por isso votarei para fechar como não clara até houver tal correção.

Comment: Só faz sentido falar-se em diagonal principal com matrizes quadradas, e o seu exemplo é uma matriz 6x5.

Answer (score 5):

Sua pergunta realmente não está muito clara. Se sua matriz é uma lista de listas, a solução é a seguinte:

```
matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9, 3, 8, 9],
           [4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4],
           [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6],
           [4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

diag = []
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    for j in range(len(matriz[0])):
        if i == j:
            diag.append(matriz[i][j])

print(diag)
```

A saída é `[1, 8, 2, 5, 5]`

Já se sua matriz é um array [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/index.html) (e se não for, eu recomendo que use essa biblioteca) a solução é a seguinte:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array(matriz)
np.diag(array)
```

E a saída é `array([1, 8, 2, 5, 5])`